# Compare char array

Tags: c++

Hi I'm doing an assignment and in this part of it I need to check if a word I have entered into a char array is equal to a word stored in a structure array. This is what I have but it doesn't work:

```
if (CDdata[i].artist == search)
```

Can someone please help me compare the item in the structure array to the char array?

Thanks.

Comment: You really could have tried to research it a little harder on your own.

Comment: for C style arrays, `==` will compare pointers. You need to use strcmp for comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `CDdata[i].artist` and `search` are `char*` or `const char*`, all you're currently doing is comparing the *pointers* not the *values*.

You need to use something like `if (strcmp(CDdata[i].artist, search))` which will return 0 for equality.

`strcmp` is a standard function in the C standard library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) function in the c standard library.

```
if (strcmp(CDdata[i].artist, search) == 0)
```

Comment: Is there any other way, I'm pretty sure I'm not allowed to use #include <string> in my assignment.

Comment: Yes, you could reinvent the wheel and implement your own version but that's a bad idea. `strcmp` is located in <cstring>.

Comment: @LeverArch: Is it mentioned in your assignment? I agree with Garee, reuse of code is considered good practise